# Iterating an array in a SQL function

Tags: sql, plsql

I am having a problem with my SQL function, I am passing in 4 params that are of type NUM_ARRAY.  My function is getting hung up at the WHERE clause in each FOR loop.  So, I am unsure on how to compare my table comlumn 'edit_id' to my particular parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DEL_BS_INFO (pLfEditDel    IN NUM_ARRAY,
                                        pRcEditDel    IN NUM_ARRAY,
                                        pSpnEditDel   IN NUM_ARRAY,
                                        pComEditDel   IN NUM_ARRAY)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   tmpVar      NUMBER;

--

BEGIN
-- If a deletion is checked on the Lost/Found table.
IF 0 < plfEditDel.COUNT
THEN
  FOR i IN plfEditDel.FIRST .. plfEditDel.LAST
  LOOP
     UPDATE   BSSS
        SET   LOST_FOUND = NULL,
              LOST_DESC = NULL,
              LOST_LOC = NULL,
              LOST_DATE = NULL
      WHERE   EDIT_ID = pLfEditDel;
  END LOOP;
END IF;

-- If a deletion is checked on the Returned Check table.

IF 0 < pRcEditDel.COUNT
THEN
  FOR i IN pRcEditDel.FIRST .. pRcEditDel.LAST
  LOOP
     UPDATE   XT_BSSS
        SET   RETURN_CHECK = NULL,
              RETURN_LOC = NULL,
              RETURN_DATE = NULL
      WHERE   EDIT_ID = pRcEditDel;
  END LOOP;
END IF;

-- If a deletion is checked on the Sponsor table.

IF 0 < pSpnEditDel.COUNT
THEN
  FOR i IN pSpnEditDel.FIRST .. pSpnEditDel.LAST
  LOOP
     UPDATE   XT_BSSS
        SET   SPONSOR = NULL,
              SPON_LOC = NULL,
              SPON_START = NULL,
              SPON_END = NULL
      WHERE   EDIT_ID = pSpnEditDel;
  END LOOP;
END IF;

-- If a deletion is checked on the Comments table.

IF 0 < pComEditDel.COUNT
THEN
  FOR i IN pComEditDel.FIRST .. pComEditDel.LAST
  LOOP
     UPDATE   XT_BSSS
        SET   COMMENT = NULL
      WHERE   EDIT_ID = pComEditDel;
  END LOOP;
END IF;

  COMMIT;
 RETURN 0;
 EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS
 THEN
    ROLLBACK;
  RETURN SQLCODE;
END XFW_DEL_BS_INFO;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this:

```
WHERE   EDIT_ID = pLfEditDel
```

to this:

```
WHERE   EDIT_ID = pLfEditDel(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

For performance reasons I would suggest you change the FOR loops into FORALL statements, e.g.:

```
FORALL i IN plfEditDel.FIRST .. plfEditDel.LAST
 UPDATE   BSSS
    SET   LOST_FOUND = NULL,
          LOST_DESC = NULL,
          LOST_LOC = NULL,
          LOST_DATE = NULL
  WHERE   EDIT_ID = pLfEditDel(i);
```

This will result in one SQL being executed, and a bulk in-bind of the array to the database - instead of the slow-by-slow processing you've got at the moment.